# Run multiple commands using wsl

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, batch-processing

I have some scripts on my home folder that I would like to run from command line, actually from the task scheduler, but I don't find the way to do so.

I have tried

```
wsl -u Ubuntu -u jlanza "cd /home/jlanza/bin && ./myscript && ./myotherscript"
```

but it doesn't work.

How can I concatenate the execution of several commands under the same session?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe -d Ubuntu -u jlanza sh -c ". ~/.profile && script-jlanza.sh"
```

This way I load my own own profile and then I'm able to run the commands.

The option is just to run sh or any shell and then execute the commands you'd like within that shell. The other answer is also valid, but I like mine most, as I'm able to use the user profile (path, aliases, etc.)

Answer (score 11):

You need to escape && so powershell does not see them as different commands, to pass && to wsl do the following:
`` wsl -d Ubuntu -u jlanza -- cd /home/jlanza/bin `&`& ./myscript `&`& ./myotherscript ``

Comment: Thanks, only solution that worked for my case!

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass those commands to WSL without the quotes so that bash interprets them correctly as a series of commands chained together, rather than a single long command. Unfortunately, when you do that, the '&&' operator gets interpreted by the Windows command line interpreter and the commands following do not get passed to WSL.

What I've found to work is replacing the '&&' (run command only if the preceeding command exits with success) operator with simple ';' (run command regardless of how the preceeding command exited). In your case then, something like this should work:

```
cmd /c "wsl -u Ubuntu -u jlanza cd /home/jlanza/bin; ./myscript; ./myotherscript"
```

However, if your use cases neccesitates the use of the '&&' operator, I'd try saving the command you're running as a script or an shell alias in the WSL. Calling that would then save you the need of passing '&&' through the Windows command line interpreter.

Comment: Thanks. I have also include my own answer. Sorry but I thought I did it a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a whole bash script (with multipe lines commands, built-ins etc.) conveniently using the following syntax. The code uses Powershell [Here-String](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-here-strings-with-powershell/) to define a multiline bash script and then pipes it to the stdin of the `bash` command using `wsl.exe`:

```
@" 
echo abc; 
h=`$(hostname); echo "Hostname is `$h";
echo "lsb_release is `$(lsb_release -a)";
"@ | wsl -- bash
```

Note that `'$'` is escaped to `` '`$' `` in powershell, to prevent variable substitution.

Here's a more complicated example, which uses an ad-hoc Ansible configuration on WSL to test WinRM connection to the Windows Host (this assumes that WinRM is already setup):

```
Write-Output "Testing Ansible on WSL connection to $(hostname) ($(Get-WindowsIp))"

# Ad-Hoc inventory written to a temp file
$Inventory = @"
[windows]
windows10 ansible_host=$(Get-WindowsIp)
[windows:vars]
ansible_user=$([Environment]::UserName)
ansible_password=$(Read-Host 'SSH Password')
ansible_port=5986
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_transport=basic
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
"@

# (Powershell) Pipe ansible test script to stdin of bash
@"
tmpfile="`$(mktemp -p /tmp/)";
cat >`$tmpfile <<"EOF"
$Inventory
EOF
# win_ping windows host, using the above inventory.
ansible windows -i `$tmpfile -m win_ping
"@ | wsl -- bash
```

`Get-WindowsIp` is defined separate to retrieve the IP address of the Windows host.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this command in CMD, do this

wsl -u Ubuntu -u jlanza cd /home/jlanza/bin ^&^& ./myscript ^&^& ./myotherscript

The trick is to escape all special characters using "^".